# expose database queries to users

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Suppose I have a table with columns 'name', 'age', 'city', 'country'. I would like to expose the database query interface to users, that is, they should be able to perform all kinds of queries that `sql` let's us do.

The only way I can think of doing this is to have a row for each column where each row is of the form:

```
column name | operator | value
```

An example query in an activity would be:

```
name | = | Bob 
age  | > | 25
```

Then with that information I could have a method perform the query and return the result. 
For this simple example it would work. But there are more interesting things one can ask `sql` and this approach would fail at a lot those queries.

What can I do about this?

Comment: The database and JDBC already [provide metadata](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) about your tables and columns, so no need for you to store that. Just ask your database to tell you what columns are in a table, their datatype, their name, etc.

Comment: The most generic mechanism would be to allow SQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to think what operations are you going to allow your users. The most common SQL queries are *SELECT*, *INSERT*, *UPDATE*, *DELETE*. Once you have the list of operations that you are going to provide, you need to think of the parameters that the user can select while making any of these queries. For example, if the user wants to fetch (SELECT) some data, what can he provide as input, in your case the age of the person. Similar case for the other queries.

So once you have the above information, you will need to convert it into a query. This can be done by creating a utility or helper class which takes into account the users query as well as parameters and forms the SQL query which you can execute on your database.

For example, lets take the StackOverflow Jobs page (https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab). Here you can see that the user can fetch data based on multiple parameters which are keyword, location, remote etc. Taking this example into consideration, your utility will create a SELECT query and pass the user selected parameters and generate a SQL query of the form

```
SELECT jobs WHERE is_remote=<user_param> AND tech=<user_param> AND compensation=<user_param>
```

This is just an overview of what needs to be done. There might be some changes based on your exact use case. But this will just about cover what you need to achieve.